# Encryption algorithms and the "One-Time pad"

Tags: xor

I am not well versed in the field but I believe I know the basics.

All encryption algorithms that I know of utilize direct data manipulation to encrypt a message (string of bits) such as shifting, cycling, etc. in specific patterns utilizing the encryption key.

Is there any algorithm that instead of touching the data-to-be-encrypted in any way instead generates a secure one time pad using a reasonably short key?

I suppose technically in this scenario you would call the key a seed for a pseudo-random number generator.

So my question is this, does such a generator exist in a secure form and with an algorithm that can turn a phrase into a key or just generate such a key.

If there is such a generator I suppose you will point out the weakness of a one time pad on changing/multiple data, but suppose it isn't a concern due to pad use markers or simply because there is no other data or changes.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stream_cipher  $\;$

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why not the one-time pad with pseudo-number generator](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/10422/why-not-the-one-time-pad-with-pseudo-number-generator) (or maybe [What is the difference between a stream cipher and a one-time-pad?](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/810/what-is-the-difference-between-a-stream-cipher-and-a-one-time-pad)).

Comment: In canon with the comment by @RickyDemer — you might want to check out http://www.ecrypt.eu.org/stream/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an entire class of ciphers that do exactly this. They're called [stream ciphers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stream_cipher). At their most basic, they pretend to be a one-time pad. You give them a small key and they generate a stream of seemingly random bits. You then XOR these bits with your plain-text to make ciphertext.

You can add bells and whistles to this basic behaviour but what I've described is the essence of the stream-cipher.

The most famous of these stream ciphers is probably [RC4](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RC4). If you ever used SSL at all then you will have used this steam cipher.

Equally, if you've ever used a mobile phone you've probably had your voice traffic "protected" with [A5/1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A5/1).

There are people who are experts in just this area of cipher design.

There's nothing more to say really other than that this is a well established branch of cryptography with a very well developed body of research and many fielded designs.

Comment: Agreed. I've deliberately picked old designs because they're closer to the essence of a stream cipher. In turn, it more closely matches the focus of the question. 

I thought introducing more sophisticated designs with nonce and/or AEAD support would have been confusing for question posed at this level. 

That's the purpose of the paragraph on "bells and whistles" paragraph, as sort of a dog whistle to people who would pounce on my choice of ciphers :)