# what is DHE_EXPORT cipher suite

Tags: diffie-hellman, tls, key-exchange

I need to know what is exactly DHE_EXPORT cipher suite and why it is still supported by some servers.
Is there any implementation or details about this weak crypto?

Comment: There seems to be an history of using that term`DHE_EXPORT`instead of `DHE_DSS_EXPORT` or/and`DHE_RSA_EXPORT` of [RFC2246](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2246.txt).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Export ciphers date back to the time when cryptography export was regulated by governments, most notably the US government (see [this answer for a good overview of the history of export restrictions](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/10688/4793)). Back then, exporting cryptography with more than 56 bit strength was forbidden. For the Diffie-Hellman Key Agreement scheme, 56 bit of security meant that they could only use 512 bit parameters (I'm going to assume that you know how Diffie-Hellman works. If not, see for example [here](https://blog.cloudflare.com/logjam-the-latest-tls-vulnerability-explained/)).

All of the remaining details of the protocol are, as far as I am aware, identical to regular Diffie-Hellman. They are a relic from past times that continually crop up and cause trouble (like in the case of [logjam](https://weakdh.org/), which is explained well in [this answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/89702/20775) and [this article](https://blog.cloudflare.com/logjam-the-latest-tls-vulnerability-explained/)). There is absolutely no good reason to support them in this day and age, and if you find a server that still allows it, you should contact their admins and tell them to disable it.

(This is also a very good reason why we should not go back to intentionally weakening cryptography, as some people have proposed lately - we tried that once and it's still hurting us, over 20 years later.)