# If Kerckhoffs's principle is correct why does the NSA not publish their Suite A ciphers?

Tags: nsa

The [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerckhoffs%27s_principle) offers little insight. To quote the page:

> the decision to keep them secret is in keeping with a layered security
>   posture

How should we (the cryptographic community) interpret the NSA's decision to keep their best ciphers private? It seems that if obfuscation works, then Kerckhoffs's principle represents an extreme viewpoint and should not be applied generally.

Comment: Related to your question, the lines *“[…states/countries always consider ignoring Kerckhoffs's principle a small price to be paid when it adds another layer of security (through obscurity).](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/10688/12164)”* and *“[The reason is that — from a military point of view — every layer of security (no matter how small) adds security. Sometimes, the smallest layer of security represents the fine line between life and death.](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/10688/12164)”* might already explain it to you.

Comment: I was adding an extensive answer (which isn't addressed by the dup e-sushi pointed the question to); the summary is: Kerckhoff's principle only says that the system should be secure if published, it doesn't mandate publishing.  Also, we recommend publishing crypto so that it can be vetted by cryptanalysists; NSA happens to have their own cryptanalysts which can do quite a fine job so they have no need.