# What is the strength of this machine?

Tags: encryption, classical-cipher, pen-and-paper

This machine has the stator, with one half of the alphabet, and three rotors with replications of the other half in different order and repeated twice. There can have two rotors in use or the full three. There is only two types of strips, SMA and SMB. These are used to differentiate what strips are used in the encrypted message. Also, SMA strips can only be used with other SMA. Ditto with SMB strips. There are 3 strips for both rotors and stators. They are numbered 1 - 3. Is this machine relatively secure compared to other classical ciphers generated by a machine?

Key: SMA123/AQZ/2

Explanation: Using strips designated SMA, stator is SMA1, the first rotor is SMA2 and the second rotor is SMA3. The letters are representing the indicator letters, letters Q and Z below stator A. The two shows how many times the last rotor moves before the one above it does.

This machine is a quite primitive machine. It is basically a St. Cyr Slide with multiple moving strips (rotors). The rotors contain only one half of the alphabet. The stator, (the stable strip) contains the other half.

i.e.
Stator: 'ABCDEFGHIJKLM'

ROTORS CAN CONTAIN ***ANY*** PERMUTATION OF 'NOPQRSTUVWXYZ'

This property makes the cipher reciprocal making encryption and decryption easier.

As a note, this machine is ***NOT*** electrical. It is moving strips of plastic with the alphabet printed on them, held in place by staples on a board.

I can give further explaining if it needs be.

Comment: What machine?  What kind of machine is it? What is a "stator"? If it is an encryption/decryption device, what is the alphabet? What does "..of the other half" refer to? What strips? What do the strips do? What are they? Why did you tag the question with "pen-and-paper" if it is a machine?  What do "SMA" and "SMB" tell us about the strips?

Comment: How is this machine related to Enigma?

Comment: Please see: https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/50444/