# Unhash possible? How got this user the unhash?

Tags: hash, 2nd-preimage-resistance

in this post [Why can't we reverse hashes?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/45377/why-cant-we-reverse-hashes) there is an unhash of "Hello World".

How did that work?   If there is no function to find it, where does it come from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You misread the question;

> First off, I know hashes are 1 way. There are an infinite number of inputs that can result in the same hash output. Why can't we take a hash and convert it to an equivalent string that can be hashed back to the original hash output?

This question is asking about the **second pre-image attack**. That is given $m$ and hash of it $h = Hash(m)$, find another message $m' \neq m$ such that $h = hash(m')$

For any cryptographic hash functions, including the MD5 and SHA-1 (that their collision resistance is broken) there is no second pre-image attack that is better than the generic one that has $\mathcal{O}(2^n)$-time for a hash function with $n$-bit output.

The example there is pedagogical.

```
string: "Hello World"
hashed: a591a6d40bf420404a011733cfb7b190d62c65bf0bcda32b57b277d9ad9f146e 

unhash: "rtjwwm689phrw96kvo48rm64unc8oetb5kmrjiuh7h8huhi6dde5n5"
        (a real string that gives the same hash as "Hello World")
hashed: a591a6d40bf420404a011733cfb7b190d62c65bf0bcda32b57b277d9ad9f146e
```

The hash function is not defined, it is not a real example, it is given to make the question more clear. If they know such an example, they would be famous!

Read the example as the hash $h$ of $m = \text{Hello World}$ is given then a second pre-image attack is executed to get the string $m' = \text{rt...5n5}$ such that it has the same hash value as $m$; $hash(m) = hash(m')$

- It [turns out](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/96156/unhash-possible-how-got-this-user-the-unhash#comment209304_96157) the hash function is SHA-256 and actually we have $$hash(m) \neq hash(m')$$

---

**Some note on the terms**

The term **unhash** is a lousy term and it is not a good term in terms of cryptography since we consider that the cryptographic hash functions are one-way functions. Since they are one way how **unhash** is possible. We rather consider finding a pre-image, that is given a hash value $h$ find a pre-image $m$ from the domain of the hash function such that $h = Hash(m)$.

Most of the websites, that keeps a rainbow table to find a pre-image of predetermined input size and together with hashes of some most common dictionary, use the incorrect terms, like [this one](https://md5hashing.net/hash/md5);

`Reverse md5 lookup, unhash, decrypt and search`

- Hashing is not encryption!

Well, the correct term is to find a pre-image, it is not *the pre-image* due to the collision, we may not get the original one.

Even the term **hash** alone is used for a function that scrambles its input or produces scrambled output. For example, we use the term **collision-resistant hash function** to indicate the aim is collision resistance like SHA-256 and SHA3, Blake2.

There are **keyed hash functions** like HMAC whose aim is constructing pseudorandom function families (PRFs) or Message Authentication Code (MAC).

Comment: The hash function in the original question is actually SHA-256, as can be verified by running `echo -n "Hello World" |shasum -a256`, we get `a591a6d40bf420404a011733cfb7b190d62c65bf0bcda32b57b277d9ad9f146e`. And once we figure that out we can confirm that the second example is fake; `echo -n "rtjwwm689phrw96kvo48rm64unc8oetb5kmrjiuh7h8huhi6dde5n5" |shasum -a 256` gives `da0dec1c790d6b6197d906cce98981d60a4dd8c8da430fc71961bafaf2a8891a`.

Comment: @LuisCasillas thanks. I've never doubted that, you proved that is not real.