# Does a conditional statement depending on a round number introduce timing attack problems?

Tags: algorithm-design, implementation, timing-attack

In a cryptographic implementation I’m playing with, there’s a round function which includes a conditional `if` statement.

Stripping the superfluous stuff, the C sourcecode looks like this:

```
void f(uint32_t *state) {
    …
    for(round = 0; round < 12; round++) {
        // functions working on state
        …
        if((round & 3) == 0) {
           // additional functions working on state
            …
        }
        …
    }
    …
}
```

Trying to check if this might introduce timing attack problems, I looked at [cryptocoding.net](https://cryptocoding.net/index.php/Coding_rules#Avoid_branchings_controlled_by_secret_data) which states:

> If a conditional branching (if, switch, while, for) depends on secret data then the code executed as well as its execution time depend on the secret data as well.

This seems to hint at the fact that, as long as the `if` function does not depend on the `state` itself (which is meant to be handled as secret), there should not be a problem because `if` in this case depends on the `round` number and not the secret `state`.

Is my interpretetion indeed correct, or does that `if` represent a potential problem regarding to timing attacks? In case my interpretetion is wrong and it represents a timing attack problem, would unrolling the loop (manually by rewriting the code) be a valid way to mitigate it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Unless the number of rounds is secret, this does indeed not represent a secret-dependent branch.

(If the number of rounds is secret, a chap named [Auguste](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/9603/12164) would like to have a word with you.  Hope you speak French or Dutch as they were spoken a century ago.)

Comment: The idea of a secret number of rounds seems just too absurd to me. That's just about the easiest thing for an attacker to learn through a timing attack. And you will almost by definition have conditional branches that depend on the number of rounds (like a for loop iterating the specified number of rounds).